# Why does the Javascript event loop require the global execution context to be finished running before executing functions in the callback queue

Tags: javascript, event-loop

It's my understanding that two conditions need to be met before an item in the callback queue can be executed:

1. All frames in the call stack need to be popped off
2. All code in the global execution context needs to be finished running

I understand the reasoning behind this if, for example a `setTimeout` was called in the global execution context, but why is the second condition necessary if a `setTimeout` was called in a local execution context. Shouldn't we only need to wait until all frames **above** the local execution context where the `setTimeout` was called are popped off?

Comment: The first condition implies the second (if I understand you correctly) ? What do you mean with "global execution context"?

Comment: That's correct. I added both conditions for the sake of completeness. By global execution context, I mean code that is not running inside a function (i.e. the frame that never gets popped off).

Comment: oh well, it kind of gets popped of. That "global execution context" execution is just a task on a queue, if that is done the event loop continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main missunderstanding lies in the "callstack" here: Lets take this:

```
  (function A() {
    (function B() {
      setTimeout(function C() {
         (function D() { })();
      });
    })();
 })();
```

First of all, the code gets initialized, A will be called, and B will be called, the callstack looks like this:

```
  [init] -> A -> B
```

now then the timeout gets set. As no code is left, the callstack unwinds, and is empty then.

Now *some time later*, the timer will trigger the callback:

```
 [timer] ->
```

And that will then call C:

```
 [timer] -> C
```

inside of C, D will be called:

```
 [timer] -> C -> D
```

as no code is left the callstack unwinds again. As you can see, A and B are not on the callstack anymore, they left it *a long time ago*. Therefore

> setTimeout was called in a local execution context. Shouldn't we only need to wait until all frames above the local execution context where the setTimeout was called are popped off?

Makes little sense, because "the context were the setTimeout" was executed in *is* the upmost execution context.

Note that execution contexts do have a parent execution context, which will live as long as its childrens live (closure), however that has little to do with the callstack.

Comment: Why doesn't the event loop just wait for the first condition(stack being empty) to be satisfied? Why doesn't it just push a callback from callback queue to call stack, first chance the stack is empty? Why is it necessary for all the global instructions to be executed before pushing callback to the stack? Btw Sorry for too many whys.